# Reading a grayscale image in java

Tags: java, image-processing

As we read a RGB image , do the shifting operations to get the R, G and B matrices separately ...Is it possible to read a gray scale image(JPEG) and directly manipulate its pixel values.And then rewrite the image ?

Ultimately I have to do the DCT operation on the gray scale image.

Answer (score 2):

The code below will read the grayscale image to simple two dimensional array:

```
    File file = new File("path/to/file");
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    int[][] imgArr = new int[width][height];
    Raster raster = img.getData();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            imgArr[i][j] = raster.getSample(i, j, 0);
        }
    }
```

Note: The `raster.getSample(...)` method takes 3 arguments: `x` - the X coordinate of the pixel location, `y` - the Y coordinate of the pixel location, `b` - the band to return. In case of the grayscale images we should/may get only the **0** band.